# How to get back the values of input while changing checkbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The snippet of code is as follows:

```js
  $('.fee_checkbox').on("change",function() {
    if ($(this).prop('checked')==false) {
      $('.actual_pay').val('0');
    }  else {
      $('.actual_pay').val();
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" class="fee_checkbox">
<input type="text" class="actual_pay" value="1000">
```

Here the default behaviour of checkbox is checked and the value of the input box with class `actual_pay` was 1000. When the user unchecks the
checkbox, the value of `actual_pay` changes to 0.

After this when the user again clicks the checkbox, I need to get back the value of 1000 but it returns 0 now. I need to get the value of 1000 when the user unchecks and checks the checkbox.

Comment: If the user enters a new value, you want to get back that new value?

Comment: Yes i need to get back the new value if there is a change in it..

Comment: Check my answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, you need to get back the new entered values, so you need to use `data-attributes`.

***Enter new values and this snippet shows how to get back those new values.***

```js
$('.fee_checkbox').on("change", function() {
  var $actualPay = $('.actual_pay');
  if ($(this).prop('checked') == false) {
    $actualPay.data('current', $actualPay.val())
    $actualPay.val(0);
  } else {
    $actualPay.val($actualPay.data('current'));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" class="fee_checkbox">
<input type="text" class="actual_pay" value="1000" data-value="1000">
```

## Docs

- [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/)

Comment: Performance wise it would be better to cache `$('.actual_pay')` in a variable

Answer (score 3):

You can store the value as `data-`

like

```
<input type="text" class="actual_pay" value="1000" data-value="1000">
```

Here is a snippet:

```js
  $('.fee_checkbox').on("change",function() {
    if ($(this).prop('checked')==false) {
      $('.actual_pay').data("value",$('.actual_pay').val()) ;
      $('.actual_pay').val( 0 );
    }  else {
      $('.actual_pay').val( $('.actual_pay').data("value") );
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" class="fee_checkbox">
<input type="text" class="actual_pay" value="1000" data-value="1000">
```